# ODE integrator for Python that allows modifying y vector at each time step

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs using the numerical integration scheme that I cannot solvers avaiable in *scipy* because I need to **modify** y values in the solver after each sucessful integration step, and y is controlled internally in scipy. Are there other packages with this capcility that can be used from python?
This is the model code I have in mind. Ofcourse, this is written for scipy, and I know the line modifying `solver.y` won't work.

```
solver = integrate.LSODA(fun=psr_model, t0=0, y0=y0, t_bound=simulation_time,first_step=1e-10, max_step = 1e-3);
while solver.t < simulation_time:
    solver.step();
    ### The line below is not a valid command
    solver.y = correct_isentropic(P_meas(solver.t), solver.y);
```

Comment: I don't think any of them have that capability. iWhy not just adjust dx/dy until the ODE goes to the y value you want?

Comment: What's the reason to modify the y values that you get from integration?

Comment: @jared This need to be done to follow an approach proposed for modeling gas chemistry in a shock-tube.  I need the integrator to march forward in time by dt and provide temperature and mole fractions (solver.y), and then temperature is modified to account for isentropic expansion

Comment: If you want more control, you can write your own integrator. You can start with forward Euler and consider upgrading to RK4 if you need more accuracy.